# Creation of new targets for CTest

Tags: cmake, ctest

What is the approach to create a new target for Ctest?

By default, the target 'test' is created and CTest can be run from

```
make test
```

Let say that this command line runs some tests defined like this:

```
ADD_TEST(my_test1 my_exe1 my_arg1) 
ADD_TEST(my_test2 my_exe2 my_arg2)
```

Is it possible to create a new target 'check' such as

```
make check
```

runs my_test1 with CTest and

```
make test
```

runs my_test2 with CTest?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `test` target cannot be modified, it will always run all tests defined in the project. You can however add custom targets `check1` and `check2` which only run the desired tests in the following way:

```
add_custom_target(check1 COMMAND 
    ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND}
    --force-new-ctest-process
    --tests-regex "^my_test1$"
    --build-config $<CONFIGURATION>)

add_custom_target(check2 COMMAND 
    ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND}
    --force-new-ctest-process
    --tests-regex "^my_test2$"
    --build-config $<CONFIGURATION>)
```